# How to switch random number of rows' column values in a dataset?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, random

Learning R code here.  Here's my dataset then I'll explain in detail what I am attempting to accomplish:

```
alp <- c("a", "b", "c","d", "e", "f")
num <- c(1:6)
my.set <- data.frame(num, alp)
```

It looks like this:

```
num alp  
1   a  
2   b  
3   c  
4   d  
5   e  
6   f
```

A dataset with 6 rows and 2 columns. (Sorry, I spent a lot of time writing this all out and I can't figure out how to include spaces for the dataset to appear nice on screen)

I need to create either a `for`-loop or a function where I can randomly select a number of rows (between 0 and 6 rows) and switch their respective column values. In other words, select a random number of rows where we strip the labels, and flip the `num` value with the `alp` value.

To get it to look something like this (given that 2 rows were selected to be changed):

```
num alp  
a  1  
2  b  
3  c  
d  4  
5  e  
6  f
```

I am doing it this way: For each row, I want to flip a coin. And if it's heads (or 0), then its column values are switched. If it's tails (or 1), nothing happens to it.

Now I have this so far, but it's throwing error messages:

```
for (j in 1:nrow(my.set)) {
  flip <- sample(0:1, 1, replace = TRUE)
  if (flip==0) {
      my.set[j,1:2] <- my.set[j,2:1]
  } else {
      my.set[j,1:2] <- my.set[j,1:2]
  }
}
```

So what am I doing wrong and how can I fix this? Any help is appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply and sample to accomplish this. apply is better than a for loop in r. You tell it what dataframe to go over (my.set), then to iterate over the rows (1 for rows, 2 for columns) then give it the function  you want. In this case, we want it to put the column number in random order, which is what "sample(length(x))" does.

```
my.set <- apply(my.set, 1, function(x) x[sample(length(x))])
```

Or if you'd really rather use a for loop, you were close.

```
my.set <- data.frame(num, alp, stringsAsFactors=F)
for (j in 1:nrow(my.set)) {
  flip <- sample(1:2)
  my.set[j,1:2] <- my.set[j,flip]
}
```

Comment: I like it! Thank you! Dang yeah I was close

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a vectorized way, there is no need for loops of any kind.
First I will recreate the dataset, and get rid of the column of class `factor`.
Then the code creates an index, `flip` and changes the respective rows.

```
my.set <- data.frame(num, alp, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

set.seed(1943)    # Make the results reproducible

flip <- which(sample(0:1, nrow(my.set), replace = TRUE) == 1)
my.set[flip, 1:2] <- my.set[flip, 2:1]

my.set
#  num alp
#1   a   1
#2   b   2
#3   3   c
#4   4   d
#5   5   e
#6   f   6
```

Comment: Wow that's amazing! Thanks!